# Dismissing the view controller in iOS mono touch

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I created a button if i do click event the view must be dismissed and show the previous view.  I used the below code:

```
     partial void canceldata (NSObject sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("canceldata");

        //NavigationController.PopToViewController(settrls,true);
                    this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);

    }
```

But this code is not working. Anybody suggest me how to dismiss the current view by clicking a button in iOS mono touch example.

Comment: Please be more specific on _this code is not working_. Crashing? Doing nothing? What's the context? Show more code.

Comment: if i click the button the current view must be dismissed

Comment: showing error i.e nsinvalidargumentexception

Comment: _Where_ is this error shown? Show us the stack trace, please. How are you binding `canceldata()` to the click event? How many view controllers do you have on the `UINavigationController`? It all would be so much easier if you showed some code, otherwise I doubt you will get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you open that controller. If it is pushed to the stack, then `PopViewControllerAnimated()` should be working. If it is presented as a modal dialog for example by

```
NavigationController.PresentViewController(new UINavigationController(new MyDialog()), true, null);
```

then you should call

```
NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

instead.